# How to group JS and CSS using Grails asset-pipeline plugin?

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I'm currently using the Grails [resources plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/resources) and I have many modules defined like this one:

```
bootstrap {
    resource url:'js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js'
    resource url:'css/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.css'
    resource url:'css/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-glyphicons.css'
    resource url:'css/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css'
}
```

This is very convenient because it groups the Javascript and CSS files together into a single conceptual Bootstrap module.

I'm looking into the [asset-pipeline plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline) now, and it appears that files can only `require` other files of the same type, which means that I now have two trees of dependencies (CSS & JS) rather than one, which is a problem because there are interdependencies, e.g., bootstrap.js depends on bootstrap.css.

Does the asset-pipeline plugin allow for declaring inter-type dependencies?  If not, what is the best way to deal with this issue?

Comment: the whole point about the asset-pipeline plugin is to combine all js files in one minified file and all css files in one minified file. because, you deliver the whole js/css stuff in one file (all of it), there is no reason, do declare dependencies at all, because everything is delivered to the client. The reason why dependencies can be defined in the resource plugin is, because it does no ship all js / css stuff at once, but rather on a per page basis... This is obviously not necessary when doing asset-pipeline.

Comment: That doesn't sound right, because you can include different JS files on different pages, each with different dependencies.  Besides which, including the CSS and JS for every single one of your pages in all of the pages you have seems like a bad idea: why would I need the CSS or JS for any page other than the one I'm on? It would just slow the page load.

Comment: sure, you can include different js files in different pages, but if you do this there is no benefit with asset-pipeline over the resources plugin. The opposite of the performance point is correct: with just one js file which is loaded with the first request, subsequent pages will not load any js at all, because of the browser-cache. Additionally, there is just one http request to be made in the first place instead of plenty of them for every page (browsers can just make a limited number of queries in paralell). It is the HTTP-header to -payload ratio, that comes into play here.

Comment: That's food for thought, thanks.

Comment: I am too missing that feature of resources plugin when using asset pipeline

Comment: Couldn't you just create multiple manifests for your combined js and css, one for each "module"? That way you can still get minified and combined js and css but control which "module" gets loaded in your GSPs? What am I missing, because that seems simple.

Answer (score 0):

I don't consider this as a problem. Organizing `JS` and `CSS` files separately (even though both belong to the same package/product such as Bootstrap) is a good thing and if the `JS` is not able to refer to the `CSS`, change the URI.

In my opinion, if you want to use Bootstrap with Grails, try twitter-boostrap.

Checkout my blog post regading [**Bootstrap CSS templating in Grails**](http://binyit.blogspot.com/2014/11/bootstrap-css-templating-in-grails.html) and if you want an example, checkout an project I did using Twitter Bootstrap [here](https://github.com/biniama/mubs).